# Javascript modular namespace pattern

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I'm trying to use a modular namespace pattern which allows me to expand the functions available within various namespaces and define them across multiple files. This is the pattern I'm using;

```
var Namespace = Namespace || {};

Namespace.SubSpace = (function () {
    var subspace = {};

    subspace.Func = function () {
        return "My Function";
    };

    return subspace;
})();
```

How can I make my namespace functions available prior to their definition? In other words how can I call `Namespace.SubSpace.Func()` without it relying on the function declaration having already been parsed?

Comment: You cannot. Why would you need that?

Comment: Are you aware that in your example, you are immediately executing the function and Namespace.SubSpace.Func is in fact undefined?

Comment: @Bergi I'd like to bundle accompanying scripts as part of a WebForms component library, so there is no guarantee that the library javascript will have been included prior to user scripts. The question is inspired by Microsoft's approach `Sys.WebForms`

Comment: Never heard about 'modular namespace' pattern. Could you add a reference?

Comment: @RedTaz: As long as the userscripts don't *use* your libary before it is included, that's no problem. If they try, there's nothing you can do against - you will need to find a way to guarantee that is's included before them (ask a more specific question about that).

Comment: @FelixKling I hadn't realised that no, I've edited the question thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Pavlo I don't think it's a recognised pattern, it's just 'a namespace pattern' which seems to me to be modular

Comment: Even after edit `Namespace.SubSpace.Func` still not a function, but plain object.

Answer (score 0):

I can get close enough to solving my problem by using an approach similar to JQuery's `ready()` function. However, it does rely on defining the root namespace before anything else. The root namespace also includes functionality which allows callbacks to be registered.

```
var Namespace = (function () {

    var namespace = {};
    namespace.ReadyCallbacks = [];

    namespace.Ready = function (callback, queueJump) {
        if (queueJump)
            namespace.ReadyCallbacks.unshift(callback);
        else
            namespace.ReadyCallbacks.push(callback);
    };

    namespace.Begin = function () {
        for (x = 0; x < namespace.ReadyCallbacks.length; x++) {
            namespace.ReadyCallbacks[x]();
        }
    };

    return namespace;
})();
```

Importantly this distinguishes between callbacks which should run before others. This allows framework modules to define sub-namespaces and functions before user scripts are executed. (Even if user scripts are loaded first).

**User Scripts**

```
Namespace.Ready(function () {
    console.log(Namespace.SubSpace.Func()); // prints "Module 1"
});
```

**Framework Module**

```
Namespace.Ready(function () {
    Namespace.SubSpace = (function () {
        var subspace = {};

        subspace.Func = function () {
            return "Module 1";
        };

        return subspace;
    })();
}, true);
```

Finally, calling `Namespace.Begin()` executes everything in the correct order. Also, since I'm using JQuery anyway, I can wrap this in `$(document).ready()`.

I'm not terribly proficient in javascript so I'm not sure how 'correct' this approach is, I'd welcome comments & suggestions.